# Reverse Proxying a Rails App in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reverse-proxy

I am looking for a way to run multiple heroku apps and serve them all under the same domain.

The reason for this is that I would like to shard my users across a number of servers, so that a user account lives on a particular app instance.
Each server will have it's own database.

The end effect is that I can push new code to one of the app instances and only users on that server will see the new code.

I looked into rack rewrite, but it does not enable you to forward a request to a different server.

A redirect is no use, as I want the domain name to stay the same regardless of what server you get forwarded to.

It is in some way a proxy.

Anybody have any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something similar myself. As far as I know you need to point your domain to a a server with nginx or somethign like that, that use rewrite rules to proxy the requests (e.g. www.yourdomain.com/blog hits the heroku app at blog-yourdomain.herokuapp.com and www.yourdomain.com/otherstuff can go to otherstuff-yourdomain.herokuapp.com).

Maybe a CDN can do that. I wish heroku offered a similar functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to do, but it sounds like if you have multiple apps that you want users to be able to access and have those users be able to use the same login credentials on other apps you are building.  Then you should use an LDAP.  Here's a tutorial that might be useful. http://corrupt.net/2010/07/05/LDAP-Authentication-With-Devise/ Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question correctly. Basically, I have one application, but I would like to run multiple instances of it on heroku, so that there is no one single point of failure. If I push new code to one instance of the app, then only that particular app will be the only one to have the latest code. My idea setup would be to have 2 instances of the application running with 2 mysql databases. Then all the odd numbered user accounts will live on app instance 1 and all the even numbered user accounts on app instance 2.

Comment: The biggest problem I am encountering is having 1 domain that will serve the 2 app instances seemlessly. So, if I am an odd numbered user, I will live on app instance 1 and will be routed to that particular app on heroku but the domain I access will not change.